# Reference and authenticity of this Quote?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-scholar

I was reading Sean.W.Anthony book of The Expeditions: An Early Biography of Muhammad and i came Across this:

"ʿAbd
al-Razzāq would remark that he never once saw Maʿmar with a book, except for
a collection of long narratives...which he would occasionally take out to consult"

And the Reference was Ibn ʿAsākir, Dimashq, 59:417, mā raʾaynā li-Maʿmar kitāb ghayr hādhihi l-ṭiwāl fa-innahu
yakhrujuhā bi-lā shakk

So i was wondering if i could the find the arabic for it and if this quote is authentic and if any other Hadith Scholars mentioned Ma'mar reading from long Narratives from a book

Comment: I guess Dimashq is a reference to Tareekh Dimashq.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you where in Tareekh Dimashq?

Comment: سمعت عبد الرزاق يقول ما رأينا لمعمر كتاب غير هذه الطوال فإنه كان يخرجها بلا شك [Tareekh Dimashq, Ibn 'Asaakir 59:417](https://al-maktaba.org/book/71/27739)

Comment: Both Ma'amar and his student 'Abd ar-Razzaaq are known to have consulted their manuscripts.